# Retain parent setup when making proxy

Tags: linked-data, parent

Currently, when I link several objects, or link a scene, I need to select each object and make them proxies individually. However, doing this results in losing the parent structure of the external file. For small and even medium numbers of objects, this is fine. However, more complex scenes will be difficult and tiresome to set up.

What is the best way to go about this? Is there a way to retain the structure? Can all the linked data be made proxies all in one go as well?